# On-the-fly Java syntax checking in vim

Tags: java, vim, syntax

First and foremost please don't scream "Use an IDE" at me. I have given eclipse a chance and it is... okay but I'm much faster in vim than eclipse.

Basically the one thing that I wish vim could do that eclipse does is syntax checking on the fly. In eclipse if you have a syntax error the line is given an error marker and the file-name at the top shows a little red thing to let you know there are errors. I have been trying to get this in vim. I've looked at syntastic (which doesn't have checkers for Java) but I can't seem to make it work. So the question remains...

Is there any way to check syntax every time I save a file with vim? Hopefully have it show up in the status line naming how many errors and what line the first error is on...

Comment: You should have a look at: http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/ as well. I like it a lot. It gives me the eclipse features and much of the VI command set.

Comment: I'm saying this very quietly, since your editor is up to you. Eclipse does have plugins to allow you to use the vi/vim keybindings in the text editor; which might let you have the best of both worlds.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility to compile at each save with an `:autocommand`?

Comment: have you considered that Eclipse isn't the only IDE for Java, and far from the best as well?

Comment: @romainl I hadn't thought of that possibility yet. Do you have any examples of how I could do that and then get the errors into the statusline somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it and it's probably and overkill, but FYI there's the [Eclim](http://eclim.org/index.html) project which attempts to bring Eclipse's functionality to vim. It claims to do [Java Validation](http://eclim.org/vim/java/validate.html) along with many more features including [code completion](http://eclim.org/vim/java/complete.html) and [code correction](http://eclim.org/vim/java/correct.html).

Comment: Eclim does this fairly well. I used it for awhile, but I ended up dumping it because it slowed me down too much (not as much as Eclipse, mind you). You may also benefit from using Vim's `make` (chaining to `ant` for Java) to make it easier to build and fix errors.

Comment: agree eclim wont help you. Found better to use ctags. And maybe will start using cscope in future.

Answer (score 8):

I realise this already has an accepted solution but vim purists might prefer to use [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic)

It comes pre-configured for many of the common languages like PHP, Java etc. Just thought I'd leave this here in case other people have the same question but don't want to run a headless eclipse server to achieve it.

Comment: I did look at Syntastic but I wasn't able to make it work for some reason. I might look back into it though thanks for the reminder.

Comment: No worries. Feel free to post a question here or on the google group if you have any issues with it and I'll try help out.

Comment: Syntastic does not support Java as far as I can tell. Please correct me if I am wrong, as I really want to be wrong on this one..

Comment: It definitely does, I do a lot of Java dev with it.

Comment: It works for Java. To try it, open any Java file. Then in command mode, type `:SyntasticCheck`.

Answer (score 2):

The new [JavaComplete](https://github.com/artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2) plugin can give you some support for Java, including for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Java, and after trying a few IDE's I went back to vim. So far I have had good experience with these two plugins

- [javacomplete2](https://github.com/artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2) - Provides omnicompletion and a number of functions to automatically add import statements, generate getters and setters, etc.
- [Neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake) - handles async code checking, using async support in either Neovim or Vim 8 (I haven't tried this in neovim yet, but I assume it should work)

A good autocompletion plugin should be installed installed also (I have javacomplete2 working nicely with YouCompleteMe)

For both of these to work, I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
augroup java
  au!
  autocmd FileType java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
  autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost *.java :NeomakeFile
  # ...
augroup end
```

Before using Neomake, I tried using [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) for linting. But that plugin has no async support, thus after writing a file, I have to wait a second or so for my vim to become responsive.